# Pull ByteArrays from database and turn them back into files to pass to a partial view

Tags: javascript, arrays, asp.net-mvc, file

I have files that are saved into my database (SQL Server) as byte arrays. What I want to do is turn these byte arrays back into files to show them in a list box as links that will open another tab. (all of the files will be pdf)

```
 public ActionResult RetrieveFiles(string vendor, string invoiceNumber)
    {
        GenericRepository<APInvoiceFileUpload> invoiceFileUploadRepository = new GenericRepository<APInvoiceFileUpload>();


        string cmd = "Select * From APInvoiceFileUpload Where Vendor = '" + vendor + "' And InvoiceNumber = '" + invoiceNumber;
        List<APInvoiceFileUpload> uploadedFileList = invoiceFileUploadRepository.GetSelectAll(cmd);
        foreach (APInvoiceFileUpload invoiceFile in uploadedFileList)
        {
            //this is the byteArray Saved in the database
            invoiceFile.InvoiceFileByte
        }

        return PartialView("_UploadFilesContainer");
    }
```

This is the controller that I want to return all of the files to the list box.

The only problem is that there isn't really a path(not that I know of) for the file. So is to turn the ByteArrays back into a file and compile a list of files to pass back to the PartialView to populate the ListBox?

Comment: Your partial view just needs a list of names and an identifier for each of your files. .  The link you are creating in the partial will point to a url that can retrieve an individual file with a separate controller action that returns a FileResult.

Comment: I think you are taking me down the right path I didn't even think about passing my original model to have the user click one of the list box items that would then transform the byte arrays back into a file while also opening a new tab. Thank you!